# Style for odd displayed children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking a way to apply some specific styles on odd (or even) children that are displayed (so excluding hidden children).
Optionnaly, if that styles applied when hidden children become displayed it would be perfect!

Here is a live sandbox : http://jsfiddle.net/zrges/1/

And here is what I visually want : http://jsfiddle.net/qJwFj/ (of course, it's only a display example, don't take care of the crappy code that I wrote for that)

I can't manage with to good pseudo classes, css selectors to handle that.

I hope to have a full css/html solution (not a js/php one, which is easier)

Thank you very much!

Comment: This has been asked a number of times (yet I'm having all kinds of trouble finding a *good* duplicate); the answer is still no, you can't do it with pure CSS selectors unless there's a pattern of some sort.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I had the same difficulties to find an answer. So if you say it's a duplicate, I'm sorry and will try to find all the answers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/qbXVV/18/

HTML:

```
<button id="toggle">Toggle it!</button>
 <table>
  <tr class="sub"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr class="tag"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
  <tr class="tag"><td>Row 4</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><td>Row 5</td></tr>
  <tr class="tag"><td>Row 6</td></tr>
  <tr class="sub"><td>Row 7</td></tr>
 </table>​
```

CSS:

```
     tr:nth-of-type(even),.bg {
        background-color: gray;
     }

    .hidden {
        display:none;   
    }​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    $('.tag').toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".sub:nth-child(4n+1)").toggleClass("bg");
});
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
tr.sub { display: none; }
​.color { background: blue; }​
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tr:visible:even').addClass('color');

    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $('table tr').removeClass('color');
        $('table tr.sub').toggle();
        $('table tr:visible:even').addClass('color');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

For tables, you can use

```
tr:nth-child(even) { // your style }
tr:nth-child(odd) { // your style}
```

or

```
tr:nth-child(2n+0) { // your style }
tr:nth-child(2n+1) { // your style}
```

Comment: The [`:nth-child`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/nth-child/info) selector only looks at the sibling position, regardless of the other selectors. So, this will not exclude hidden children, as requested in the question.